# Error when running dnsmasq

Tags: dhcp, dns

When i try to start dnsmasq ,I face the following error `dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Adress already in use`

Answer (score 1):

Given the information provided I'd say you already have a DHCP server running on that machine.

Perhaps you have started dnsmasq more than once?

Try the following command to see if anything else is acting as a DHCP server on port 67.

`sudo netstat -tulpn|grep 67`

Comment: Thank you,, I've got this when typing the command             udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                                                      474/dnsmasq

Comment: That just shows that dnsmasq is running.  Did you start it?

Comment: No i didn't but i think it's related to dnsmasq-base program thats implemented natively into the os as I read in an other forum